# compilation error in adding an element from a jlist 

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm trying to add element from a Jlist to another , append if this the correct term 
while searching i found this code and tried it but it doesn't work

```
ListModel made_model = made_list.getModel(); // 1

Object[] orig_sel = orig_list.getSelectedItems(); // 2

Object[] new_made_model = new Object[made_model.size() + orig_sel.length]; // 3

// this block is 4
int i = 0;
for(;i < made_model.size(); i++) 
    new_made_model[i] = made_model.getElementAt(i);
for(; i < new_made_model.length; i++) 
    new_made_model[i] = orig_sel[i - made_model.size());

made_model.setListData(new_made_model); // 5
```

the error is in this line

- made_model.setListData(new_made_model); // 5
  it tells me to cast made_model to Jlist , which i did but then while running the class , i get this error
- javax.swing.JList$1 cannot be cast to javax.swing.JList

Comment: can down-voter share reason for that, because I think that this question is valid +1

Comment: Not the down-voter, but a link to the erroneous code might be instructive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setListData()` is a method of JList, not of ListModel. You can't cast a ListModel to a JList.

Your code should be:

```
madeList.setListData( newMadeModel );
```

Edit:

Instead of playing with Arrays to create a new model just use a DefaultListModel:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
```

Then you can add Objects directly to the model without using indexes:

```
model.addElement(...);
```

When you are finished you add the model to the list:

```
list.setModel( model );
```

This way you are less likely to make a mistake when playing with the indexes of the 3 Arrays.

If you need more help then accept this answer (since it was about a compile error) and post a new question with a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demontrates the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! but , I tried it and no errors is shown but still when i select two item and transfer them to other jlist , it display only the last selected one .

Comment: Well, your question was about the compile error which I solved. Now you have a programming error which you need to solve. See my edit for a suggestion.